# Property 'getValue' does not exist on type 'Subject<boolean>'

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs5

I am using **Angular2**. I have a `BehaviorSubject`.

```
isOpen$: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

When I use like this to get latest value

```
isOpen$.getValue()
```

It works well, but the terminal gives me the warning:

> Property `'getValue'` does not exist on type `'Subject<boolean>'`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining it as a `Subject<boolean>` but assigning it from `BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true)`. In **TypeScript** the type of the property is redundant when you assign it. Remove the declaration like this:

```
isOpen$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

Then the static analyzer will correctly handle it as you'd expect. The type `Subject<boolean>` does not contain the `getValue` method.

Comment: @HongboMiao, happy to help

Answer (score 3):

```
isOpen$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

Then the static analyzer alao knows `getValue()` exists.

`Subject` doesn't have a `getValue()`